# Asynchronously getting data instead of using initWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, nsstring, nsurl

I am currently using this code to get data from a URL: 
`NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstring];
    NSString *stringfromFB = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];`

I was wondering how I could gather this data asynchronously so that my app does not freeze everytime I need to execute this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Do not alloc init URL obj. for local use.
NSString *urlString = @"put your url string here";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

The above delegate methods are of NSURLConnectionDelegate, where you need to handle all things like response error etc.. It is by default provided so we can directly override it without

I have use once in my project It will work for async request but If you received number of images as well then also use **IconDownloader** or **EGOImageView** which implements the lazy loading of image and make much low chances of freezing of app.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is available in os5 like this:

```
NSString *stringfromFB;
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstring];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (data) {
        stringfromFB = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  // note the retain count here.
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}];
```

If you're stuck in os<5 for some reason, you'll need to start your connection with a delegate, and implement the delegate protocol [as illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124421/are-there-complete-examples-that-make-use-of-all-the-nsurlconnection-delegate-me) (and many places elsewhere).

Comment: above example is missing a ] at the end, but apart of that is amazing! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstring]; 
    NSString *stringfromFB = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]
});
```

Comment: Does GCD automatically do multi-threading for you? Sorry if simple question, I have no experience with this yet. Thanks!

Comment: if you use dispatch_async and dispatch_get_global_queue, YES. It's a implementation of TASK PARALELISM, very easy to use and very powerful (supports multi-core). You can read about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html . Is always my first choice for paralelism in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

if you don’t want to wait for a connection to complete loading a url, you can load it asynchronously using NSURLConnection.

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:
  [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:yourUrlString]]
   delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that NSURLConnection is deprecated you need to use NSURLSession.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: request
                                        completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *networkError) {

            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

            if ([httpResponse statusCode] == STATUS_OK) {
                // use data                     
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Network Session Error: %@", [networkError localizedFailureReason]);
            }
}];

[task resume];
```